# Filter DataFrame by rows which have no "missing" value

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a DataFrame that may contain missing values and I want to filter out all the rows that contain at least one missing value, so from this

```
DataFrame(a = [1, 2, 3, 4], b = [5, missing, 7, 8], c = [9, 10, missing, 12])
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b        c
     │ Int64  Int64?   Int64?
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │     1        5        9
   2 │     2  missing       10
   3 │     3        7  missing
   4 │     4        8       12
```

I want something like

```
 Row │ a      b        c
     │ Int64  Int64?   Int64?
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │     1        5        9
   4 │     4        8       12
```

Ideally, there would be a filter function where I can pass each row into a lambda and then do a combo of `collect` and `findfirst` and whatnot, but I can't figure out how to pass lambdas to `subset` or `@subset` (from DataFramesMeta), because I don't only have three columns, I have over 200.

Comment: There is already a function for this case, `dropmissing(df)`. See [the documentation](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/man/missing/)

Comment: I should be better at reading the docs. I guess with Julia being so easy to code in I got out of the habit of checking if there are library functions for what I need. Can you post yours as an answer please, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following what @Antonello said you can do it with `dropmissing`. You have three options:

- `dropmissing`: create a new data frame with dropped rows with missing values;
- `dropmissing` with `view=true` create a view of the source data frame with dropped rows with missing values;
- `dropmissing!` to drop dropped rows with missing values in-place.

By default all columns are considered, but you can change it and pass a column selector specifying which columns you want to include in the check.

Finally by default after dropping rows with missing values the columns will change their `eltype` not to allow missing values, but you can change this behavior by passing `disallowmissing=false` in which case they would still allow them.

Here is how you could perform filtering using `subset` and `ismissing` instead:

```
julia> subset(df, All() .=> ByRow(!ismissing))
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b       c
     │ Int64  Int64?  Int64?
─────┼───────────────────────
   1 │     1       5       9
   2 │     4       8      12
```

(I am using standard `select` from DataFrames.jl)

or if you have a very wide data frame (like thousands of columns):

```
subset(df, AsTable(All()) => ByRow((x -> all(!ismissing, x))∘collect))
```

(this is a special syntax optimized for fast row-wise aggregation of wide tables)

Comment: Indeed I must find ways of keeping up with Julia, I end up using it only a few times a year and I keep forgetting all the things I have learned.

Comment: @Morpheu5 no prb, you can accept (if it satisfies you) this answer, mine was just a link to the documentation...

Comment: I will then expand on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this seems to work but I'm leaving this open for more suggestions.

```
DataFrame(collect(filter(r -> nothing .== findfirst(collect(ismissing.(collect(r)))), eachrow(data[:, before_qs]))))
```